# How to do a containsAll() in HQL on a one-to-many set?

Tags: hibernate, hql

I have difficult to add the criteria that matches the Java collection contailsAll(). Say I have a project class which has a set of strings which contains the participating student IDs. If I have a list of student IDs as {"101","121", "131"}, and what to be able to create a query that list the projects that containsAll() those three student IDs. Is it possible to do it in HQL and is it possible to do it using the Criteria? Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

List lists=em.createSqlQuery("SELECT id FROM project pro WHERE pro.id IN ( 101, 121, 131 )";

if(list.size()==3)
 return true;
else
return false;

Comment: thanks for replying but my problem is not for the ID but for the one-to-many relation set, where the pro.studentIDs is a set of IDs and I would like to compare this ID set with another value set.

Comment: send your entity classes for project and students .